# Track change in html elements using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


username = ""
password = ""
url=""
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, )
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter User Id']").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter Password']").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Sign In"]').click()
sleep(4)
driver.get("")
sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-1hwfws3').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]").click()

driver.fullscreen_window()
```

It is a dynamic element hence I had to give full Xpath.It is a dropdown.

If the user comes to this page and changes the drop down option, is there any way to automatically replace this xpath in my code with the newely selected option's xpath so that next time we execute the code it goes to the newely selected option.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]").click()
```

Am new to this please help me out.

Thank you

Comment: can you share the html or any images for the drop down?

Comment: @Mat

<div class="css-k1-menu">

<div class'css-l1'>

<div class="css-d0i-option" id="react-select-2-option-0" tabindex="-1">L1</div>

<div class="css-fks-option" id="react-select-2-option-1" tabindex="-1">L 2</div>

</div>

</div>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML.

Comment: You can use class name to select dropdown.
driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-k1-menu').click()